# How to preload freemarker templates?

Tags: freemarker

We are using URLTemplateLoader for loading templates hosted on a web server.
My Template engine app is multithreaded.
We do have the template caching 'on' however, if multiple request goes in 
 HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response

How can we cache the templates before hand?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I came up with is having one master template having #include all the template and execute the master template with a scheduler when cache expires. This process downloads the cache when it hits the #include in the freemarker template.

Comment: You can just call `Configuration.getTemplate` for those templates. I guess that's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement throttling in your `TemplateLoader` implementation, and set that as the template loader in the `Configuration`. It should just delegate to another `TemplateLoader`, but add throttling around it.

Although, it probably would be better if instead the source server (which now gives 429) is more forgiving when it's really just asked to do its duty.

Comment: Please suggest in detail(example), how can I implement throttling in the my TemplateLoader? All concurrent thread have its on instance of TemplateLoader.

Comment: @RamneekHanda Why do all threads have its own `TemplateLoader`? The `TemplateLoader` is normally a singleton. Anyway, inside the `TemplateLoader`, you could use a `Semaphore` that's shared among all the threads, and do the HTTP request only after the thread has acquired a permit from the `Semaphore`. So then your application will block instead of flooding the remote HTTP server.